# Problems with CSP in the manifest.json file

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, content-security-policy

the script of my first GC extension doesn't work when loaded as .crx . i've checked the debugging section and this is my error:

Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://www.lolking.net/".
 popup.html:8

Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://www.lolking.net/".
 popup.html:9

so i guess the error is from the manifest.json file:

```
{
"name": "LolKing Searcher",
"version": "1.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Search your LoL profile",
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.lolking.net/; object-src 'self'",
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*/"
],

 "content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://*/*/","https://*/*/"],
  "js": ["popup.js"]
}
],

 "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "LolKing Searcher",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
}
}
```

also every advice is well accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error, as it says in the error itself, is in your `popup.html` file. You can't have any inline code in html files, that includes inline event handlers like `onclick="dosomething()"`. Move all of your inline code to an external file.

Example:

**popup.html**

```
<head>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="userText" placeholder="Enter Summoner's name"  />
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Search"/>
</body>
```

**popup.js**

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",check,false);
};
function check(){
  var val = document.getElementById("userText").value;
  if(val != ""){
    var url="http://www.lolking.net/search?name=" + val;
    chrome.tabs.create({url:url});
  }
  else
    alert("Please enter a name");
}
```

Also you need to remove your `content scripts` section because you are trying to inject your popup code into every page which just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: sorry for being noobish, should i move these inline event handlers to the js file?

Comment: something like this?                          document.addEventListener("onclick", Check, false);

Comment: i've tried this but it doesnt work  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("onclick", Check, false);

Comment: can you help me one more time please?

Comment: @GinoGinuzzi I updated with some edits to your code, let me know if there are any problems with it.

Comment: Thank You so much for your help! i guess now it's time for me learn how to use APIs :).